# MySQL connections from client programs persists

Tags: mysql, vb.net

In a college where I'm employed, we are currently testing (dry-run) the new enrollment system I have developed. The application has several modules (accounting, cashiering, course scheduling, admission, advising, grading) installed in different offices. We are using MySQL Server 5.1 and the front end was developed using VB.Net.

The system has 1 computer server and 25 clients.

I have noticed, using MySQL Administrator, that the clients' connections persists although   I have used **using** syntax for all my data access/manipulation codes. I thought after **end using** statement the connections would automatically be released.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to find that using doesn't always close files and connections, esp if there was an exception thrown, so I just use a try..finally block to ensure that the connection is definately closed, regardless of what happened in the application.

So, just try it without the using and use a finally block to close the connection and see if that fixes your problem.